# express.JS .push cousing array to be undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Hi for some reason everytime i try to push data into my array i get a error returned saying the array is undefined

```
         function getPosts(initial){


        var data = {};

         if ($scope.user){

           data.ids = angular.copy($scope.user.friends);
           data.ids.push($scope.user._id)

        }

        $http.post('api/social/getPost', data).success(function(response) {

            if (initial) {

                $scope.wallposts = response;

                if (response.length == 0) {

                    getPosts(true);

                } else {

                    $scope.wallposts = response;

                }

            } else {

                if (response.length > $scope.wallposts.length) {

                    $scope.IncomingPosts = response;

                }

            }

        });

    };
```

this is the error

```
Error: data.ids is undefined
getPosts@http://localhost:3000/client/controllers/PostController.js:48:16
@http://localhost:3000/client/controllers/PostController.js:105:9
invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:4604:16
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</</instantiate<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:9855:24
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8927:34
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8226:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8229:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8229:13
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8229:13
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8973:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8226:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8106:30
compilationGenerator/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8447:20
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:8244:1
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:9020:20
ngIfWatchAction@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:25059:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:16664:23
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:16928:13
done@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:11266:36
completeRequest@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:11464:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular/angular.js:11405:1
```

however if i remove the line that pushed the id into the array everything works fine?

the code on the server side is

```
module.exports.getPosts = function(req, res){

//get all friends and users posts
Posts.find( {postedBy: {$in: req.body.ids}} )
    .sort({postedOn: -1})
    .exec(function(err, allPosts){

        if (err) {

            console.log(err)

        } else {

            res.json(allPosts)

        }
    });
```

};

all i am trying to do is gather all ids from the users friend then add the users id to the array so i can use a $in query to search mongo for all posts that have been created by them ids.

i have spent 5 days on this bug and to be honest i have no idea what is going on

here is the full code for the client side in case it helps

```
(function(){

    angular.module('Scrimbox')

     .controller('postsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$interval', '$routeParams', function( $scope, $http, $interval, $routeParams){


        $scope.newPost = function(){

            var request = {};

            var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("User-Data"));
            var userId = user["_id"];
            var useravatar = user["avatar"];
            var username = user["username"];

                var request = {

                    postedBy: userId,
                    posts_avatar: useravatar,
                    username: username,
                    content: $scope.postContent

                };


            //send to server
            $http.post('api/social/newPost', request).success(function(response){


                  getPosts(true);

            }).error(function(error){

                console.log(error);

            });
        };

         function getPosts(initial){


            var data = {};

             if ($scope.user){

               data.ids = angular.copy($scope.user.friends);
               data.ids.push($scope.user._id)

            }

            $http.post('api/social/getPost', data).success(function(response) {

                if (initial) {

                    $scope.wallposts = response;

                    if (response.length == 0) {

                        getPosts(true);

                    } else {

                        $scope.wallposts = response;

                    }

                } else {

                    if (response.length > $scope.wallposts.length) {

                        $scope.IncomingPosts = response;

                    }

                }

            });

        };

         $interval(function(){

            getPosts(false);

            if ($scope.IncomingPosts) {

                $scope.difference = $scope.IncomingPosts.length - $scope.wallposts.length;

            }
             console.log("this is working");

         }, 5000);


        $scope.newP = function(){

            console.log('getting new posts');

            $scope.wallposts = angular.copy($scope.IncomingPosts);
            $scope.IncomingPosts = undefined;
        }

        //Init
        getPosts(true);

    }]);
}());
```

Comment: What is output of `console.log($scope.user.friends);` before `data.ids = angular.copy($scope.user.friends);` and `console.log(data.ids);` after `data.ids = angular.copy($scope.user.friends);`

Comment: her is output of console.log($scope.user.friends) 56d9809b51c6e4d8329f785f,56d9809b51c6e4d8329f785f

her is output of console.log(data.ids)56d9809b51c6e4d8329f785f,56d9809b51c6e4d8329f785f

Comment: this is what is being posted after it all

{"ids":["56d9809b51c6e4d8329f785f","56d9809b51c6e4d8329f785f","56d7f0923e1fb1b03699d8af"]}


and this is the response

[{"_id":"56dfd89986e1617039ca55f9","posts_avatar":"https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/scrimbox/avatar3
.jpg","username":"stacka","postedBy":"56d7f0923e1fb1b03699d8af","content":"hi","__v":0,"likes":"0","postedOn"
:"2016-03-09T08:02:33.684Z"},]

Comment: however it is displaying this error if i leave the .push in the code 

Error: $scope.wallposts is undefined

Comment: and needless to say nothing is displaying in the ng-repeat are

but if i remove the .push then everything displays and works just fine except i have no results from the users ID which is something i need

Comment: this is the servers error if i leave the .push in the client side
`code
POST /api/social/getPost 200 439.418 ms - 10048

{ [CastError: Cast to string failed for value "[object Object]" at path "postedBy"]

  stack: 'Error\n    at MongooseError.CastError

  message: 'Cast to string failed for value "[object Object]"
 at path "postedBy"',

  name: 'CastError',

  kind: 'string',

  value: { userId: '56d7f0923e1fb1b03699d8af' },

  path: 'postedBy',

  reason: undefined }
 code`

Comment: Well the error is obvious. One or more ids in req.body.ids is an object with userId property. Add `console.log(req.body.ids)` before Posts.find on the server to see which one it is

Comment: Gotcha. Found the object and that is fixed but still getting data.ids is undefined if i un comment the push.

Comment: Ok can you try `console.log(data.ids instanceof Array)` before push?

Comment: Sure. 
ok it returns false on the first run then 5 secounds later when it runs again it returns true

Comment: So maybe $scope.user.friends is undefined the first time so angular.copy assigns undefined to data.ids, quick fix could be after `data.ids = angular.copy($scope.user.friends);` do this `if(!data.ids || !data.ids.length) data.ids = []`

Comment: yup that fixed it mate thank you very much.

so the issue was that $scope.user.friends was not defined before the code was running to copy the value from $scope.user.friends

is that a error caused by the order i am executing controllers

Comment: In the controller i can't see where $scope.user.friends comes from so it's hard to tell what's going on

Comment: None the less I appreciate your help mate your a solid person

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers by Molda.

> So maybe $scope.user.friends is undefined the first time so
>   angular.copy assigns undefined to data.ids, quick fix could be after
>   data.ids = angular.copy($scope.user.friends); do this if(!data.ids ||
>   !data.ids.length) data.ids = []